# How can I add double arrow (≫) collapse buttons to sections?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

How can I customize a notebook so that sections have double arrows (≫) which open and collapse the whole section?

[image]

Comment: In addition to following Domen's answer, choose `Format->Cell Dingbat->FilledSquare` from the menu to get the square.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make the cells be of some heading type by going to the menu  `Format > Style` and choosing any of `Title/Subtitle/Chapter/Section/...`

Then simply close the enveloping group of cells by double-clicking on the right-most grey lines. The opening button `»` will be automatically produced.

[image: Closing groups]