# How can I make Subsubsection collapsible?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

In my work, I’ve encountered the need to make sections of level ‘Subsubsection’ collapsible. Sections of higher levels are collapsible by default. However, I’m unable to make Subsubsections collapsible.
In contrast to sections of higher level (Title/.../Subsection), Subsubsection's enveloping group cannot be close by double-clicking on the right-most grey lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add double arrow (≫) collapse buttons to sections?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259061/how-can-i-add-double-arrow-%e2%89%ab-collapse-buttons-to-sections) It works normally for subsubsections ...

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? I have no troubles collapsing subsubsection in [version 13.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBxEI.gif).

Comment: My current version of WM: 14.0.0.0